# Display contents of one html file in another html file in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

What I want is to separate my styling codes from the main Html code in a Google Apps Script Project. For example let us say I have this:

**File1.html:**

```
    <html>
      <h1>This is a sample page</h1>
    <html>
```

**File2.html:**

```
    <style>
      #h1 { color:red}
    </style>
```

So what should I do to apply the style written in ***File2.html*** to the contents of ***File1.html*** ? Yes, I know that I can create external style sheets in private servers or Google Drive & include them in the project. But I want all the codes of the project to be contained in the project itself.

Comment: copy and paste it to the other file and it will be fine. only ecternal style sheets makes it available on both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("file.html");
page.cssStyles = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("file2.html").getContent();
return page.evaluate();
```

in **Code.gs** will pull **file2.html** and add it to file1.html, if you then add the following code at the top of **file1.html**, after the opening `<html>` tag.

```
<?!= cssStyles; ?>
```

This prints **file2.html** inside of **file1.html** (and any other files you want). This is also an easy way of including libraries/frameworks like Bootstrap.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. There was a small correction required to your code though. The **.getcontent()** method should be added to **page.cssStyles** declaration. Otherwise the HtmlOutput Object itself would be printed out as a string rather than the code contained in it. I have edited your code for those who will refer to it later. Anyways, thanks for your time & effort.

Comment: Fixed a typo in this answer; getcontent should be getContent.

Comment: The new Best Practices page in the documentation has a neat method that I like and hadn't thought of. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="some.html">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object type="text/html" data="some.html">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can use this old way...if possible